# Why does Xcode still show up as an available update in App Store after being installed?

Tags: mac-appstore, xcode, software-update

[image: Screenshot of App Store]

I have installed the update shown from the App Store. I have since started and used XCode. Why does this update still show up in the updates list for App Store?

Is there some extra action I need to take to complete the update?

Link to screenshot: http://d.pr/i/dp3z

Comment: Your screenshot didn't show up. Did you already download and install the update? I assume so, but would be good to confirm.

Comment: What does Xcode>About Xcode say?

Comment: About Xcode says version 4.5.2

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but is this after quitting the app store app? I have noticed that this page doesn't refresh.

Comment: Been happening for a while, AppStore has been quit and reopened. Hell the whole machine gets shut down every night.

Comment: I've noticed the App Store is a bit flaky with clearing installed updates: I've even gotten notifications that updates are available only to find myself looking at the screenshot above. :P

Answer (score 4):

Was having the same problem after installing Xcode v4.6 on a system with Mountain Lion, had Xcode v4.5.2 & v4.4.1 (with different names) also installed in the Applications directory. Read on a different thread that Spotlight indices can sometimes cause problems, followed the steps outlined here:

http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2409

This fixed my problem. (YMMV)

Comment: In my case I had an old xCode.app sitting in a subdirectory in my Applications folder because I'd re-downloaded it to pull out the simulator and SDK.

Answer (score 1):

For me this was because I had 2 different versions of xcode one in `/Applications` and another in `/Developer/Applications`

if you copy the current version from `/Applications` into `/Developer/Applications` overwriting the old version that's there, it should disappear from the updates section when you restart the App Store.

I believe this issue was caused by upgrading from Snow Leopard to Lion.